# How to create a MainWindow instance from another instance of the application (Mutex / Single Instance related)?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using a Mutex to ensure that only one instance of the application is able to run at any given time.

I allow the user to close the MainWindow but I keep the application running with the ability to open another instance of the MainWindow by double clicking the Notify Icon in the system tray.

What I want to do is create a new instance of the MainWindow in the currently running instance of the application (the one that was started first), if the MainWindow is not currently opened, whenever the user attempts to run another instance of the application.

I've found that I'm able to restore a current instance of the MainWindow from another instance of the application by using the Windows API messaging system, but if the MainWindow is closed, the WndProc function naturally doesn't receive any messages, so I can't use that.

I also thought about calling Hide() on the window when the close button is clicked instead of actually closing the window instance, but I can't get the window fade animation to display when using Show(). From the other posts I've seen about the Show() function, the animation only displays the first time you show the window after it has been created.

Here's the code for my App.xaml.cs, if it helps:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    bool singleInstance;
    mutex = new Mutex(true, UniqueMutexName, out singleInstance);

    if (!singleInstance)
    {
        NativeMethods.PostMessage((IntPtr)NativeMethods.HWND_BROADCAST, NativeMethods.WindowsMessage.WM_INSTANCEATTEMPT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        Current.Shutdown();
    }
    else
    {
        // create the NotifyIcon if this is the only instance
        NotifyIcon = (TaskbarIcon)FindResource("NotifyIcon");
    }
    base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

In the above code, the window message just checks if the window instance is minimized and restores it if so. Any other ideas of things I could try?

Comment: Broadcasting a window message to activate your own app is not a nice idea. Additionally, there is no point in initializing a WPF app (including loading of resources etc) for just sending a message. This costs performance. You have to re-design you solution. Use an interproc communication mechanism like named pipe or mailslot to listen for activation events. Initialize/send messages in the `Main` method - before the WPF subsystem initializes.

Comment: IPC is new to me (other than WindowsMessages), so I had to do some research to try to get this to work and there might be something simple I'm missing. I managed to get named pipes working in C#, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to open a MainWindow in one instance from another. Do you have any sample code?

I did find a way to do this using the Windows Messaging system, but it requires a hidden window to be open at all times to route the messages since if you close the MainWindow, no window is available to receive the broadcast message.